# F# Akka.NET agents performance optimization when synchronizing

Tags: performance, optimization, f#, mailboxprocessor, akka.net

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have some agents running in real-time, with a large heartbeat of couple of milliseconds, and the order of operations they process for this reason are mostly deterministic (as the message processing is not the bottleneck).

Now, I am running a large amount of simulations of the system where I no longer have a heartbeat (otherwise it will take a couple of centuries) - but I need to make sure the order of operations are preserved. For this, I adopted the following solution: the simulator makes sure each agent has processed his message queue, by posting a dummy synchronization message and blocking while waiting for the answer. This does work for my application, but the time it takes is not intuitive - as a single threaded implementation would be an order of magnitude faster (I guess - x 100 ish - although I have not tested ).

I have isolated a small test that shows the issue, even trying to use another library, akka.net

```
type Greet = 
| Greet of string
| Hello of AsyncReplyChannel<bool>
| Hello2  

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let system = System.create "MySystem" <| Configuration.load()    
    let greeter = spawn system "greeter" <| fun mailbox ->
        let rec loop() = actor {
            let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
            let sender = mailbox.Sender()
            match msg with
                | Greet who -> () // printf "Hello, %s!\n" who
                | Hello2 -> sender.Tell(true)
                | _ -> ()
            return! loop()
            }
        loop()

    let greeterF =
        MailboxProcessor.Start
            (fun inbox ->                
                async {
                    while true do
                        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                        match msg with
                        | Greet who -> () // printf "Hello, %s!\n" who
                        | Hello reply -> reply.Reply true
                        | _ -> ()
                    }
            )

    let n = 1000000

    let t1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    t1.Start()
    for i = 1 to n do
        let rep = greeterF.PostAndReply(fun reply -> (Hello reply)) |> ignore
        ()

    printfn "elapsed Mailbox:%A" t1.ElapsedMilliseconds

    t1.Restart()

    for i = 1 to n do        
        let res = greeter.Ask (Hello2)
        let rr = res.Result
        ()

    printfn "elapsed Akka:%A" t1.ElapsedMilliseconds
    System.Console.ReadLine () |> ignore

    0
```

Basically, both take about 10 seconds for a mere 1 millions of synchronizations - and not computation what-so-ever involved, and this is... unfortunate.

I am wondering if anybody has come across the same problem and if there is anyway to switch off the overhead forcing everything to run in a single threaded mode... something like better than de-activating all the cpus but 1 in the bios - or writing a clone of the whole system without the agents.

Any help well appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this overhead will be noticeable with the real computations in place? That being said, I've had great experiences with [Hopac](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac), which purportedly has significant overhead savings.

Comment: The real computations behind each are mostly numerical down to a bunch of elementary operations - at most couple of memory allocation here and there. I think there is not much way around - the locking/thread switching etc.. is an order of magnitude slower. I guess I have to throw some hardware at it.. sounds silly but works.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the Akka.NET version beeing slow here is how you communicate with the actor:

```
main process    Task     FutureActorRef  !!ThreadPool!!   greeter
    Ask ---------------------->
                              Tell-----------> 
                                             MailboxRun ----->
                                 (greeter mailbox is empty)  |                 
                               <--------------------------Tell 
                  <--Complete task
    <----------.Result
```

1. For each iteration, a TPL task will be created
2. Then a **single message** is sent to the greeter.
3. The main process then blocks while waiting for the response to come back.
4. The greeter replies back which in turn completes the task inside the `FutureActorRef`

Rinse and Repeat..
This design will cause Akka.NET to start and stop the greeters "mailbox run" for each message as the mailbox queue becomes empty for each iteration.
This results in threadpool schedulation for each single message that is passed.

> It's a bit like entering your car, putting the pedal to the metal, then abruptly stop and step out of the car, and then repeating the procedure again.
>   That is just not a very effective way to travel fast.

@Aaronontheweb's suggestion will only have effect if you work out the above kinks in your code.
The mailbox needs to be able to constantly pick messages of the internal queue to work with messages in batches to achieve full throughput.

Instead, separate the producer from the consumer.
Create an actor that listens for the responses from your greeter.
And once that actor have processes your 1000000 messages, let that actor send a WorkCompleted message back to the consumer.

[Edit]
I gave it a shot myself, I don't know F# so it might not be completely idiomatic :)

```
open Akka
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.FSharp

type Greet = 
| Greet of string
| Hello of AsyncReplyChannel<bool>
| Hello2 

type Consume =
| Response
| SetSender

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let system = System.create "MySystem" <| Configuration.load()    
    let greeter = spawn system "greeter" <| fun mailbox ->
        let rec loop() = actor {
            let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
            let sender = mailbox.Sender()
            match msg with
                | Greet who -> () // printf "Hello, %s!\n" who
                | Hello2 -> sender.Tell(Response)
                | _ -> ()
            return! loop()
            }
        loop()

    let consumer = spawn system "consumer" <| fun mailbox ->
        let rec loop(count,sender : IActorRef) = actor {
            if count = 1000000 then sender.Tell(true)
            let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
            match msg with
            | Response -> return! loop(count+1,sender)
            | SetSender -> return! loop(count,mailbox.Sender())

        }  
        loop(0,null)      

    let n = 1000000

    let t1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    t1.Start()   
    for i = 1 to n do        
        greeter.Tell(Hello2,consumer)

    let workdone = consumer.Ask SetSender
    workdone.Wait()

    printfn "elapsed Akka:%A" t1.ElapsedMilliseconds
    System.Console.ReadLine () |> ignore

    0
```

I updated your code to use a separate consumer for the actor responses and then reply back once all replies had been processed.

By doing so, your processing time is now down to 650ms on my machine.

If you want better throughput, you need to involve more actors to parallelize more.

I'm not sure if this helps in your specific scenario

Comment: For my particular application, I think that is a low hanging fruit to reduce the sychronization frequency, to an acceptable level. I still have to synchronize as different message get processed with some implicit time consistency.     The other suggestions seems more involved at the moment - I think i'll revisit this when I get a chance. I also observed that some syncrhonization "loop", i.e. agent 1 synch with 2 who sync with 3 etc.. was faster than doing the synch from the main thread

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly modified `MailboxProcessor` version:

```
module MBPAsync =
  type Greet = 
   | Greet of string
   | Hello of AsyncReplyChannel<bool>

  let run n =
    let timer = Stopwatch.StartNew ()

    use greeter =
      MailboxProcessor.Start <| fun inbox -> async {
        while true do
          let! msg = inbox.Receive()
          match msg with
           | Greet who -> () // printf "Hello, %s!\n" who
           | Hello reply -> reply.Reply true
      }

    Async.RunSynchronously <| async {
      for i = 1 to n do
        do! Async.Ignore (greeter.PostAndAsyncReply Hello)
    }

    let elapsed = timer.Elapsed
    printfn "%A" elapsed
```

The difference here is that this version uses `PostAndAsyncReply` and keeps the computation in an async workflow.  On my quick test this seemed to be much faster that using `PostAndReply`, but YMMV.

The timings I get from the above MBP version look roughly like this:

```
> MBPAsync.run 1000000 ;;
00:00:02.6883486
val it : unit = ()
```

A comment earlier mentioned my Hopac library.  Here is an optimized version using Hopac:

```
module Hop =
  type Greet = 
   | Greet of string
   | Hello of IVar<bool>

  let run n =
    let timer = Stopwatch.StartNew ()

    let greeterCh = ch ()
    do greeterCh >>= function
          | Greet who -> Job.unit ()
          | Hello reply -> reply <-= true
       |> Job.forever
       |> server

    Job.forUpToIgnore 1 n <| fun _ ->
        let reply = ivar ()
        greeterCh <-- Hello reply >>.
        reply
    |> run

    let elapsed = timer.Elapsed
    printfn "%A" elapsed
```

The timings I get from the above Hopac version look roughly like this:

```
> Hop.run 1000000 ;;
00:00:00.1088768
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: Hi @user3841986, is there any actual variant of the hopac version? Seems some operators are not existing in the code base anymore

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an F# developer, but I'm a core dev on Akka.NET. A couple of ideas for your scenario:

1. If you're only using a single actor for this work, you can try using a `PinnedDispatcher` - that way the actor runs on its own dedicated thread all the time. That will save you on unnecessary context switching overhead.
2. You can also set the throughput of the mailbox to be much higher for this `PinnedDispatcher` than the normal settings. i.e. set a throughput value of 10000 (or something) instead of the normal 25. Assuming that the contents of your mailbox grow in large bursts this should save you on mailbox synchronization overhead.

Here's what your dispatcher configuration might look like:

```
 my-pinned-dispatcher {
      type = PinnedDispatcher
      throughput = 1000 #your mileage may vary
 }
```

And then configure an actor to use it

**C# Fluent Interface**

```cs
var myActor = myActorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<FooActor>()
.WithDispatcher("my-pinned-dispatcher");
```

**Config**

```
akka.actor.deployment{
   /greeter{
     dispatcher = my-pinned-dispatcher
   }
}
```

These are both options you can configure via HOCON in App.config or Web.config or you can use the fluent interface on the `Props` class to do this. Also worth noting: [there's a bug with pinned dispatchers at the moment](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/850), but that should be fixed in our next maintenance release (v1.0.1,) which should be out next week.

Your mileage may vary, but this is what I would try - basically it's just designed to help reduce contention and overhead around a single actor.